# Unable to use JSON from S3 buck in i18next

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-intl, react-i18next

This is how my `i18n` file looks like -

```html
import i18n from 'i18next'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
  .use(HttpApi)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    // resources: resourcesObj,
    initImmediate: false,
    backend: {
      loadPath: 'https://bucketlink.amazonaws.com/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      crossDomain: true,
      allowMultiLoading: true,
    },
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: false,
    ns: ["translations"],
    defaultNS: "translations",
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: true
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

When I change the language I see i my Network tab that the JSON is coming from S3 properly. Though, the key is being displayed instead of values in all my screen. Can someone let me know why my translation values are not displaying.

Note -- If I use resources and put my json object inside of it, it works as expected.

Comment: Check that aws returns the proper content-type header

Comment: @felixmosh - `Content-Type: application/json` is the header type

Comment: Do you see the json file downloaded properly? (in the network tab), can you show this app for debugging?

Comment: @felixmosh - Here is the playground link - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-forked-poi7m?file=/src/i18n.js

I put the debug to `true` and it is giving me - `i18next::translator: missingKey en` error

Answer (score 0):

From the demo that you've posted, the problem is that your json files (the ones that are stored in s3) are not in the right format.

You need to split the json file by lang & namespace (`translations` in your case), and the json files must contain only the keys that are relevant to the `lang` & `namespace`.

For example, your folder should look like:

```
└── locales
    ├── en
    │   └── translations.json
    └── he
        └── translations.json
```

and each `translation.json` file should contain:

```json
{ 
  "Overview": "Overview",
  "TaskList": "Task List"
}
```

PS, your translation files can be a nested object, then you will need to specify the key with a `dot notation` (something like `a.b.c`)

Comment: I made changes accordingly, still, the issue is there - 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-forked-poi7m?file=/src/i18n.js

Comment: pay attention, currently your s3 holds javascript object (not a JSON, JSON must be have double quotes).
Just put my example in s3, and try again

Comment: I have replaced Javascript obj with a JSON though the problem is still there. I have console logged the data and the json is getting printed in logs, I am completely clueless why it is not working as expected - could you please check the recent changes?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-forked-poi7m?file=/src/i18n.js

Comment: Still, the json is not valid :|
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9304194/94602684-e2048480-029d-11eb-95d3-a8cde43616a8.png

Comment: so sorry, just removed the trailing comma at the end, still it persists :( :(

Comment: Is it the same code sand box? because now the file is not accessible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222263/discussion-between-felixmosh-and-pushpendra-yadav).

Comment: I have been working on it, however, you should be able to see. Happy that it got resolved, I have asked about it on another forum and got a reply -

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-forked-e531z?file=/src/i18n.js

have a look, language detector is removed and it worked for this case.